# File.walk.forEach only prints directories, but no files

Tags: file, kotlin, foreach

I'm so confused.
I'm just using one line, which is the same on every tutorial website:

```
File("/storage/emulated/0/Music").walk().forEach() {
   println(it)
}
```

But it only prints directories, and no normal files.
Why?

Comment: Can you give some details of your platform, set-up, etc.? (It shows files as well as directories for me.) Could it be a file permissions issue?

Comment: Im using Kotlin, Android Studio on Linux, ive manually uploaded some files on to the AVD using the Device File Explorer.

Now that you say with the permission, do i have to add some permissions?
I already have ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ``` in AndroidManifest.xml and also android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Ive just saw the files have the permission -rw-------, is that enough?
I dont think so actually, because it should be -rw-r--r--, right?
Nevermind, ive just tested the app on my phone, where the permission are definitely correct, still only get directories

Comment: Check the permissions on the directories — listing files needs read permission on the directory they're in, not on the files themselves. Also, the effective permissions depend upon the user running the code as well as the file/directory's user: `-rw------` is enough only if they match. (But I don't know about phone OSs. As I said, it might help if you could give some details.)

Comment: Have you had a look at how [permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) and [file storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) work on Android?

Comment: @gidds The permissions on the dirs are all drwx, think thas good? And what details do you exactly need? My code maybe?
https://github.com/azndd/music/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/aznd/first/SettingsActivity.kt
My first problem was that im using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to open this DocumentProvider so the user can choose a directory. But that only returned an URI, But File("/storage/emulated/0/Music").walk().forEach() doesnt seem to work with URI, so ive used an function that ive found, its the getPath func. That returns an actual path. Maybe there is a problem with that?

Comment: @gpunto i will do that, hopefully i can get some useful information out of it to fix my issue.

Comment: @gpunto oh man i really feel stupid, i didnt even give the permission, ive implented
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
and also saw that it wasnt even granted. Now everything works as expected. Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem as me:
Make sure you granted the app the permission...

Comment: Which permission? Be explicit.